# Are docker image digests really secure?

Tags: docker, hash, docker-registry, docker-image

How does docker handle digests?

I can see in plain text, when I run `docker image --inspect`, the digest of an image.  And there's also the thing that local images don't have a digest until I push them to a registry (and AFAIK, if I push an image to various registries, it will have various digests, but never tried that).

I fear that docker might be actually using that info instead of calculating the hash every time that I use or pull an image.

Is there a way to actually tell docker: "Hey, I want you to recheck right now the hash of the image contents.  Are they the exact same as when I first created the image?  Or has someone manipulated it ever?"

And: does docker really calculate that hash every time an image is run (by digest), or at least every time an image is pulled (by digest)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The digest is calculated on push and pull to a registry. It's a sha256 checksum of the image manifest, which is current versions of docker is independent of the registry (the older schema v1 syntax included the repository/tag in the manifest that resulted in the digest changing depending on the image name). The layer digests are included in that manifest, and those digests on the registry are compressed tar files. Once the files have been extracted on the local docker engine, they aren't reverified, and I'm not aware of a command yet that would verify the files under `/var/lib/docker` have not been changed since the image was pulled.

Comment: So then, `docker pull` using digest is safe even from an untrusted registry, given that the local engine calculates the sha256 checksum of the contents, and checks that they match what you asked for, right?

Comment: @alx yes, the digest ensures what you pull has been unmodified. This is how Notary v1 works, verifying a tag points to a digest, and the docker engine verifies the rest of what is pulled automatically.